# django redirects to non existing url

Tags: python-3.x, django

Two days ago I created a django project and it worked all right. But, now when I am working on another django project still when I run server it's redirecting me to the older project.  I am using different virtual environment for both of them. Even after deleting the old one the issue is not resolved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share more details or any other configuration you have used for django project

Comment: As others mentioned it's most likely a caching issue. If Django is redirecting URLs with a 301 Moved Permanently response, your browser will cache that and do the redirect on its own. You can verify this by opening the network inspector in your browser and try visiting the page, most likely you'll see it redirect. Clearing the cache should solve this.

Comment: Thanks, it was browser cache issue only. After clearing cache its working alright. How can i be so stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, This is not a Django error. I also faced this issue. This is your Cached issue. You can try in incognito mode or clear your browser history and cached.....This error will be solved.

**Thank You !!!**

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when server of both projects are running and running on same port. can you verify?